# Django Split a charfield output which is seperated by ','(comma) into an array of strings.?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

template.html

```
{{ profile.tag }}
```

views.py

```
class ProfileView(CanEditMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
   template_name = "profile/profile_view.html"
   queryset = User.objects.all()
   context_object_name = 'profile'
   slug_field = "username"`
```

gives output as **"tag1,tag2,tag3"**

is there ant way to do it in django itself?

i want output as shown below[image: required -output image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way to solve the problem by adding additional function in the `models.py` file

models.py

```
def tags_list(self):
    return self.tags.split(',')
```

template.html

```
{% for tag in tags_list %}
    <p>{{ tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

simple and easy!

Comment: The idea behind helps when you must store an array of strings, but you're using mysql, if you're using postgres though, I highly recommend you use [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, split the comma value `CharField` field like this:

```
class ProfileView(CanEditMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "profile/profile_view.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    slug_field = "username"`

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # get parent context
        # the model here should be replaced with the object that has the "tag" attribute. DO NOT use the "model" word.
        # Try self.object.tag.split(',')
        tag_list = model.tag.split(',')  # conversion from a string to a list
        context['tag_list'] = tag_list  # add to the context the tag_list list
        return context
```

and then in your template simply iterate over it:

```
{% for tag in tag_list %}
    <p>{{ tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i have already declared a context, is there a way i can override to declare more than one? i am a newbie

Comment: i have edited my view above. what do i need to change in the view?

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: no it does not work, it outputs as a single string without "," a (comma).

Comment: OK. Let me understand you want the string `'cat1,cat2,cat3'` to be converted to `['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']` ??

Comment: yes! thats exactly i want. now i am getting `['tag1 tag2 tag3']`

Comment: You do know the difference between a string and a list, aren't you? You want a string to be converted into a list. That's what you asked, right?

Comment: according to your code i get the source as`<p>#tag1 tag2 tag3</p>`
i want the output as `<p>#tag1</p><p>#tag2</p><p>#tag3</p>` you get my question now?

Comment: Updated my answer. Just include the `{{ tag }}` inside `<p>`. Also, where the `#` came from??

Comment: **to explain my problem clearly**
`{% for tag in tag_list %}
    <p>#{{ tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}` should give `<p>#tag1</p><p>#tag2</p><p>#tag3</p>` right? i am getting `<p>#tag1 tag2 tag3</p>` **You get my question now?**

Answer (score 0):

The correct way works, but I would use the `list` built-in method to just change the string from array.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    string_array = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def pass_to_list(self):
        return list(self.string_array)
```

### Notes:

- Remember that your string array must be an actual array on the database, with '[' and everything
- This way works by taking use of the built-in `list` method, but you can also just return the string splitted by commas